# Return full status with code using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am sending a JSON request using cURL in PHP. On a validation error the API that I am hitting will return a 400 error. If I use the chrome extension Postman, I see the entire status with the code seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYknZ.png

However when I post using cURL, this is what I receive from curl_getinfo:

```
(
    [url] => https://**sensitive**/
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 400
    [header_size] => 157
    [request_size] => 315
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.929666
    [namelookup_time] => 0.000949
    [connect_time] => 0.201551
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.741269
    [size_upload] => 173
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 186
    [download_content_length] => 0
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.929631
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Is there a way to get the entire status message from cURL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the entire http_code from the headers.

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$headers = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
```